# dplyr Properly using the gather function

Tags: r, dplyr

There should be an obvious solution using ddplyr gather function but say i have a table

```
   condition  learnedtogether same_block same_session      mean
1               1           FALSE      FALSE        FALSE 0.8309669
2               1           FALSE      FALSE         TRUE 0.8051708
3               1            TRUE       TRUE         TRUE 0.8681102
4               2           FALSE      FALSE        FALSE 0.8188932
5               2           FALSE      FALSE         TRUE 0.7697297
6               2            TRUE       TRUE         TRUE 0.8899083
7               3           FALSE      FALSE        FALSE 0.8742560
8               3           FALSE       TRUE         TRUE 0.8915900
9               3            TRUE       TRUE         TRUE 0.8927894
```

How do I gather the data so that I have 3 columns

```
condition   LearningType      mean
1             learnedtogether   .86
1             same session       .8
1             different Session .83
```

Where learnedtogether, same_block, and same_session are all collapsed into one row.

thanks in advance.

Comment: Note that `gather` function has been superseded by the `pivot_longer` function. No more updates/improvements shall be made to this function. You should rather use the `pivot_longer` function. Anyway using `gather` you could do: `gather(df, name, val, learnedtogether:same_session)`

Comment: I don't see how you can `gather` (or `pivot_longer` for that matter) on this data, as it expect the mean to be in the column row. Wouldn't a `case_when` do the trick here? Something like: `mutate(LearningType = case_when( sum(learnedtogether, same_block, same_session) == 0 ~ "different session", sum(learnedtogether, same_block, same_session) ==  1 ~"same session", TRUE  ~ "Learnedtogether"` (or if the sum doesn't work that way, you could specify `learnedtogether == TRUE & same_block  == TRUE & same_session == TRUE ~ "learnedtogether" ` etc

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the order is repeated (eg 1st value in `condition` should have a value of `"different Session"` in column `LearningType`, 2nd value in `condition` should have a value of `"same Session"` in column `LearningType`) then you can utilize the fact that dataframes will recycle values of atomic vectors that are not the same length as the number of rows in your dataframe:

```
df$LearningType <- c("different Session", "same session", "learnedtogether")
df[,-(2:4)]
```

**Output**

```
  condition      mean      LearningType
1         1 0.8309669 different Session
2         1 0.8051708      same session
3         1 0.8681102   learnedtogether
4         2 0.8188932 different Session
5         2 0.7697297      same session
6         2 0.8899083   learnedtogether
7         3 0.8742560 different Session
8         3 0.8915900      same session
9         3 0.8927894   learnedtogether
```

---

Otherwise, you can `rowSum` your logical columns and utilize them like so:

```
library(dplyr)

v <- c("different Session", "same session", "?", "learnedtogether")

df %>% 
  mutate(LearningType = v[as.numeric(ordered((rowSums(.[2:4]))))]) %>% 
  select(-(learnedtogether:same_session))
```

Though it's not clear from your question what to do when `same_block` and `same_session` are the only `TRUE` values in the row.

**Output**

```
  condition      mean      LearningType
1         1 0.8309669 different Session
2         1 0.8051708      same session
3         1 0.8681102   learnedtogether
4         2 0.8188932 different Session
5         2 0.7697297      same session
6         2 0.8899083   learnedtogether
7         3 0.8742560 different Session
8         3 0.8915900                 ?
9         3 0.8927894   learnedtogether
```

---

**Data**

```
df <- structure(list(condition = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 
3L), learnedtogether = c(FALSE, FALSE, TRUE, FALSE, FALSE, TRUE, 
FALSE, FALSE, TRUE), same_block = c(FALSE, FALSE, TRUE, FALSE, 
FALSE, TRUE, FALSE, TRUE, TRUE), same_session = c(FALSE, TRUE, 
TRUE, FALSE, TRUE, TRUE, FALSE, TRUE, TRUE), mean = c(0.8309669, 
0.8051708, 0.8681102, 0.8188932, 0.7697297, 0.8899083, 0.874256, 
0.89159, 0.8927894)), row.names = c(NA, -9L), class = "data.frame")
```

Comment: If you need to apply some combination that uses conditional logic for `learnedtogether`, `same_block`, and `same_session` then it might be worth using `case_when` as suggested by @Annet. From your question it's not clear what the conditions are for assigning values to your `LearningType` column.